# C console application - file/header organization and compiling

Tags: c, struct, compilation, console, console-application

I'm having a hard time organizing multiple `.c` and `.h` files into my console application project - and also, I'm a little unsure on how the compiling command should be written. I'm gonna list my files and the (relevant) code on them:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <structs.h>
#include <search.h>

int main () {
    ...
    search();
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

structs.c:

```
#include <structs.h>

typedef struct {
    ...
} Brand;

typedef struct {
    ...
} Car;
```

structs.h:

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H

typedef struct {
    ...
} Brand;

typedef struct {
    ...
} Car;

#endif
```

search.c:

```
#include <search.h>

Car *search () {
    ...
    Car cars[255];
    ...
    return cars;
}
```

search.h:

```
#ifndef SEARCH_H
#define SEARCH_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <structs.h>

Car *search ();

#endif
```

The compilation command that I'm writing is `gcc -o main structs.h search.h main.c`. The terminal is displaying the following errors:

```
search.h:6:10: fatal error: structs.h: No such file or directory
main.c:6:10: fatal error: structs.h: No such file or directory
```

I have researched everywhere, watched C tutorials again and again, looked at some similar problems here on StackOverflow - everything I tried just switched this problem for others (other files "missing"). Thanks in advance and sorry for the sloppy english!

Comment: remove the .h file from the gcc command line

Comment: Use `gcc` as follows: `gcc -o main [Your C files] -I[Path to the folder containing the .h files]`.

Comment: A) You don't compile `.h` files directly. B) Use `make`, `cmake`, or *something* to automate your builds. There are many templates for these and tons of examples to work from.

Comment: You seem to be writing in C.  This is a separate language from C++, though the two are related.  There is no such thing as "C/C++".

Comment: Use the double-quote form of `#include` for headers included with the project itself: `#include "structs.h"`.  This is conventional for uninstalled headers, and as long as all the sources and headers are in the same directory, it will very likely also resolve your "No such file or directory" issue.

Comment: Also, there is no good reason for `structs.c` to duplicate the structure definitions and typedefs of `structs.h`.  In fact, in older versions of C, duplicating the typedefs is erroneous.

Comment: In this comment I'll check if I 100% undertood everything you guys commented and Brad's response, is that ok?

1. Switch "<>" for """" to include uninstalled headers in all ```.c``` files;
2. Delete the ```structs.c``` file, since it is redundant;
3. Rename ```structs.h``` as ```carinfo.h```;
4. Rewrite the compiling command as something like ```gcc -o main main.c search.c -I search.h carinfo.h```.

Is that it?

Comment: @MatheusCaetanoRocha: `-I` needs a path after it. You cannot use it alone. Or omit it if the header files are in the same directory as the source files. And do not list header files on the compile command line. Header files are included by using `#include` directives in source files and in other header files, not by passing them to the compiler.

Comment: @Matheus Caetano Rocha, As `search.h` does not need library includes: `<stdio.h>, <stdlib.h>`, better to leave them out of that header file.  `search.h` should include all the headers needed for itself and no others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual method for include local include files is to put them in quotation marks rather than angle brackets.

So your main should start with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "structs.h" 
#include "search.h"
```

The compiler will check the current folder for the include files, and:

```
cc -o main main.c search.c
```

will work.  The other method to indicate to the compiler where include files are located is the `-I` option.

```
cc -o main -I . main.c search.c
```

Other stuff:

"structs.h" is not a good name, it doesn't tell anyone looking at the code what the header file is for.  How about "carinfo.h"?

Comment: In this comment I'll check if I 100% undertood your response and the comments in my question from other people, is that ok?

1. Switch "<>" for """" to include uninstalled headers in all ```.c``` files;
2. Delete the ```structs.c``` file, since it is redundant;
3. Rename ```structs.h``` as ```carinfo.h```;
4. Rewrite the compiling command as something like ```gcc -o main main.c search.c -I search.h carinfo.h```.

Is that it?

Comment: Correct.  And you need to have the search() function defined in a .c file somewhere (I created a `search.c` for testing purposes).

Comment: @BradLanam: No, their compile command is not correct. They need `-I <directory>`, not `-I` alone, except they do not need it at all if the header files are in the same directory as the source files. And they should not list header files on the compile command line.